# Passport login redirection

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-facebook

I'm using passport-facebook for logging into the site using facebook(the implementation is complete and working good) .Now ,  I want to redirect the user to a page containing a form which they are supposed to fill once they login from fb, and without doing it (that is without filling the form and submitting it)  they shouldnt be able to access any other links on the site.

Here is the approach I thought of: Once the user logs in I would make a Database query inside the strategy to see whether they have previously submitted the data, if they have already submitted I would set the `session.filledOrNot = true` in the object which I'll be returning to the done callback and use this property to either allow them to proceed or redirect back the same page.

Is this a good approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in 2 ways.

1.You can either make the user the fill the form while sign up/registration(whatever you call it). If the user doesn't fill the form, don't let them sign up at all.

2.The second way is what you are suggesting. Let the user sign up with out filling the form and once the user logs in, check in your database where your  condition *"session.filledOrNot = true"* is satisfied or not. The disadvantage is you need to make this query in every api request, not just the login request.

Comment: I do the second way, although I query the user instance from the database for every request and that contains a `registrationDone` boolean that requires sign up to be completed before accessing protected routes.

Comment: i was not sure whether setting up session data to test this is,is an usual and normally followed approach or this is something which i was not supposed to try ! Thank you :)